# Is there a React shorthand for passing props?

Tags: reactjs

I am tired of doing this all the time:

```
<Elem x={x} y={y} z={z} />
<Elem x={this.props.x} y={this.props.y} z={this.props.z} />
```

Is there a way I can get something like this to work?

```
<Elem x, y, z />
```

or

```
<Elem {x, y, z} />
```

Comment: Did you try `<Elem {...this.props} />`.

Comment: It works for stateful. But what if I have stateless component like const Elem({ x, y, z })? It has no this.props. Also, what if I want to pass only specific props down the line, not all of them?

Comment: I think the same logic applies for stateless components as well (they still can receive props - you can check this by logging `this.props` in the constructor method of the component). Regarding your second question - you would need to manually pass them down in that case. Or you can extract the needed props to a separate variable and pass it down to the component using the spread operator. `{...this.extractedProps}`

Comment: Does stateless even have constructor? this.extractedProps is a good advice, thanks!

Comment: not exactly since these are functions. but the props fed down to them are basically arguments anyway. you should be able to access these arguments directly in your component like any normal function. Ill update the comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As specified in the comments , you should use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) as a shorthand of sending multiple arguments to the component.

`<Elem {...this.props} />`

If the Elem component is a stateless component , you should be able to access the props just like any argument passed on the component. You probably dont need to use the `this.props` keyword in that case.

Comment: FYI this is considered [bad practice](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md).

Answer (score 72):

If your variables are contained in an object, such as `this.props`, you spread the object:

```
<Elem {...this.props} />
```

Otherwise, you spread a new object containing the variables you need:

```
{...{ x, y, z }}
```

Although it creates a new object for no good reason.

Comment: This gets computed to object assign. It would be better if it just creates a new object when you just provide an object and immediatelly spread it

Answer (score 7):

it should be noted that this only works for objects. for example:

```
this.props = {
  x: 'foo', 
  y: 'bar',
  z: 'baz',
}

const {
  x,
  ...allOtherProps
} = this.props

<Elem { ...allOtherProps } /> // works (allOtherProps is an object)
<Elem { ...x } /> // does not work (x is not an object)
<Elem x={ x } /> // works
```

Comment: `<Elem {...{x, y, z}}/>`

Comment: `{ ...allOtherProps }` - misleading