# use shorthand for object property assigment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using the following code

```
   function(props){

...
    this.props.appName = this.options.appName || this.props.appName;
          this.props.host = this.options.host || this.props.hos;
          this.props.endpoint = this.options.endpoint || this.props.endpoint;
          this.props.appPath = this.options.appPath || this.props.appPath;
    
       ....
```

Before I was using the `or` (||) I've used something like

`this.props = Object.assign(this.props, props);`

I've many fields which I need to assign is there a way to make it shorter?

Comment: How about this:`this.props = {...this.props, ...this.options}`?

Comment: Why you give up the `Object.assign` way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: [react shorthand for passing props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620847/react-shorthand-for-passing-props)

Comment: seems like a potential bug because values of `0`, `""` and `false` will be replaced too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `spread operator` here to unpack the values from other object, while keeping the first one as default.

```js
var props={appName:'name', host:'host', appPath:'path'};

var options={appName:'UpdatedName', appPath:'pathUpdated'};

props = {...props, ...options};

console.log(props);
```

**UPDATE**

In case of undefine, I think you can iterate object using `for..in` loop, to settle the data:

```js
var props={appName:'name', host:'host', appPath:'path'};

var options={appName:'UpdatedName', host:undefined, appPath:'pathUpdated'};

for(let item in options){
  if(options[item]) props[item] = options[item];
}

console.log(props);
```

Comment: if options holds a falsy (e.g undefined) property, the || operator would have kept the props property while here you are setting that falsy property to props

Comment: but what happen if `options` is undfiend so that loop will not start

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```js
var props={appName:'name', host:'host', appPath:'path'};
var options={appName:'UpdatedName', appPath:'pathUpdated'};

props = Object.keys(props).reduce((target, key) => {
  target[key] = options[key] || props[key];
  return target;
}, {});
console.log(props);
```

Comment: thanks, im using it in typescript and got error on the `target[key]` , `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.`  any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: I tried the same on typescript, working fine. Any particular framework?

Comment: no, just using `eslint recomended ` which is integreated with webstorm

Comment: tried the same on Angular 6 -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/copytaskshorthand, Typescript -> https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can do destruction:

```
  let {appName, host, endpoint, apPath} = this.props;
  let {appName: appNameOptions, host: hostOptions, endpoint: endpointOptions, apPath: appPathOptions} = this.options;

  appName = appNameOptions || appName;
  host = hostOptions || host;
  endpoint = endpointOptions || endpoint;
  appPath = appPathOptions || appPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your given snippet you just need to change the option in Object.assign().

```
this.props = Object.assign(this.props, this.options);
```

This should be work for you.